Forced Light mode is not working after package change
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Base.Theme.appTheme" parent="Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your light theme here. -->
    <!-- <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_light_primary</item> -->
</style>

<style name="Theme.app" parent="Base.Theme.appTheme" />

The app was working absolutely fine with Min SDK target 24, but as soon as I changed the package name, forced light mode is not working any more.
I tried this
<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
but it require minimum api 29+ but I don't want to do that, since my app was working fine before package change.

If you have both themes.xml(day/night) delete the night themes.xml, if you are using Jetpack Compose you can configure it via Theme.kt
